# Hot Chocolate GraphQL - How to resolve field that uses ignored field with projection

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I have a data model `ItemData` as follows :

```cs
class ItemData
{
  public string StartTime { get; set; }
  public string EndTime { get; set; }
  // other fields here
}
```

I would like to expose those two as a single field `Duration` like this. Without exposing the `StartTime` and `EndTime`

```json
{
  "duration": {
    "start": "12:34",
    "end": "23:45"
  },
  // other fields here
}
```

And types `ItemType` and `DurationType`

`ItemType` defined a field `"duration"` like this

```cs
descriptor.Ignore(x=> x.EndTime);
descriptor.Ignore(x=> x.StartTime);
descriptor.Field("duration")
    .ResolveWith<TheResolver>(resolver => resolver.GetDuration(default!))
    .Type<DurationType>();
// other configurations here
```

The endpoint is marked with `UseProjection` and use EFCore data context.

When `TheResolver.GetDuration()` gets called it did not fetch the value for `StartTime` and `EndTime` from database. I think it's because the `UseProjection` tell it not to.

Is there any way to configure the Hot Chocolate to use projection on ignored fields `StartTime` and `EndTime` when the query requests `duration` field?

Specifying `descriptor.Field(x => x.StartTime).IsProjected(true)` does not work if the field specified as ignored.

UPDATE : Just found an issue on their github, looks like they're working on it ([Issue #4192 - It's not possible to project an ignored property](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/4192))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround for the issue in your particular case, you could make the selection with duration directly from queryable like:

```
dbContext.Items.Select(i => new ItemData { Duration = new Duration { Start = i.StartTime, End = i.End } })
```

And that IQueryable with the ready duration field to return further to [UseProjection] and whatever.

Comment: Thank you @ademchenko, it took me this long to get back to this issue. I think your solution works. What I do is adding `[NotMapped]` property with calculations in the `ItemData` class directly.

Answer (score 0):

[@ademchenko's workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73405659/313666) works. But what I ended up with was to add a `Duration` property in the `ItemData` class with calculated getter/setter in a partial class to separate from original code. Inspired by that answer.

```cs
partial class ItemData
{
  public string StartTime { get; set; }
  public string EndTime { get; set; }

  // other fields here

}

partial class ItemData
{
  public Duration ItemDuration
  {
    get => new Duration { Start = this.StartTime, End = this.EndTime };
    set => (this.StartTime, this.EndTime) = (value.StartTime, value.EndTime);
  }
}
```

*Use property name `ItemDuration` to distinguish the type name and property name in this example*

Comment: In your approach, you will probably lose the ability to add filters that map directly to the database, like items.Where(i => i.Duration.EndTime < DateTIme.Now).